Oracle APEX 23.2 - How to Import/Export Translations & Dynamic Translations
I have an application (ID: 100) and created a working copy (ID: 102) to work on a new feature of translating the main application (ID: 100). After completing the translations in ID:102, I went to merge the working copy back into the main application and received an error learning that translations are not supported when merging working copies back into the main app.
What is the best way forward to get the ID:102 translations into ID:100? Application ID:100 is already deployed to both our UAT & PRD environments so need to get these changes into ID:100 to deploy.
So far I:

exported a copy of the main application (ID:100)
exported a copy of the working copy application (ID:102)
merged all non-translation changes into the main application (ID:100)



How do I get the 7 translated mapped languages from ID:102 into ID:100?

How do I get the 40+ dynamic translations created in ID:102 into ID:100?


